# cannot insert duplicate key in object exception ef

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to update a record in the database using the given code:

```
DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
            if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                DbSet.Attach(entity);
            }
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

After this I call Save Changes. I get the error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint and  Cannot insert duplicate key
>   in object. The statement has been terminated.

Although this approach is working in other tables. Any suggestions??

Comment: This question contains not enough detail to get answers. Check entities to be saved  using debug and watch in Visual Studio.

Comment: have checked them they contain the composite key values of the inserted entity but what i don't understand is why ef is trying to update them as well as they remain the same and therefore resulting in this clash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception was being thrown because I had not declared the primary key as composite key in one of the tables.

```
HasKey(t => new { t.THIRDTABLEID, t.FOURTHTABLEID });
```

Moreover I had also not because of this correctly defined the relationship as one key was missing. The exception was being thrown at the above code so I posted it. Here is how I solved it link: [The number of columns specified must match the number of primary key columns EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173341/composite-key-relationship-exception-ef)